# LARAVEL creating excel file using phpexcel dynamically

Tags: laravel, phpexcel, export-to-excel

how to make table like this, with phpexcel, and dynamic days and months ??

[Screenshot](https://image.prntscr.com/image/RsJO7QVLRSeCesTMRw7Q1g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$excelData[] = ['Report']; 
$data = $user->get();
$grandTotal = 0;
$verticalCount = [];
$verticalCount['S. No'] = '';
$verticalCount['Name'] = 'Total';
$keys = [];

foreach($data as $d=>$k){
        $_excelData = [
            "S. No" => $d + 1,
            "Name Of Admin" => $k->name
        ];

//$dates containing date of given time period 
foreach ($dates as $date) {
            $_excelData[$date] += 1;
            $verticalCount[$date] += 1;
        }

    }
```